# Howto use SimpleLocalizedStringProperty (controlsfx-plugin) with ResourceBundle in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, internationalization, resourcebundle, controlsfx

I am working with the **controlsfx** plugin and I came across an implementation for the StringProperty which is of type: `SimpleLocalizedStringProperty` and is imported from: 
`import impl.org.controlsfx.i18n.SimpleLocalizedStringProperty;` Has anyone worked with this property; according to its name it should ease the usage with a ***ResourceBundle*** I assume. But there are no tutorials nor detailed info about how to bind it with locale-based ResourceBundles.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone here would be able to share with us his/her experience with this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is supposed to load stings with a specific pattern from a `ResourceBundle` and keep other strings as they are. If a string starts with `@@`, the rest of the string is used as a key to the [`controlsfx.properties` properties file](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/8.0.5/controlsfx.properties?av=f).

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    SimpleLocalizedStringProperty prop = new SimpleLocalizedStringProperty("Hello World");
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.textProperty().bind(prop);
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        prop.set("@@font.dlg.title");
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

My recommendation however: **Do not use the class at this time!!!** (July 2016)

It contains some fundamental flaws:

- The `getValue` method is overwritten to return the localized result. Many methods, including `getValue`, use the `get` method however, which can lead to unexpected behaviour. Just replace

  ```
  btn.textProperty().bind(prop);
  ```

  with

  ```
  btn.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(new SimpleBooleanProperty(true)).then(prop).otherwise((String) null))
  ```

  in the above example and the key of the property us used instead of the localized value.

  `get()` and `getValue()` are supposed to return the same value, which this class doesn't do and therefore violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle).
- The value can change without an update being triggered. By changing the `Locale` using e.g. `impl.org.controlsfx.i18n.Localization.setLocale(Locale.FRANCE);` (assuming a Locale other than `FRANCE` before the change) will change the value returned by `getValue()` without notifying listeners.

Comment: Hi Fabian, I really appreciate that you took great effort and much of your time to write this highly comprehensive and detailed explanation. Unfortunately `SimpleLocalizedStringProperty` hasn't matured yet, I ask you whether you could recommend any i18n frameworks or coding approaches to make StringProperty to load its content from ResourceBundle that were previously injected  via `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(URL, ResourceBundle)`? With SceneBuilder one can make any textnode load from ResourceBundle with `text="%keyValue"`, is there anything similar to this for StringProperties?